# cakephp read get variable

Tags: php, cakephp

I am parsing a value from a HTML element in cakephp and is being sent via Ajax to the following url;

```
 getquestion.json?data[Job][qs1]=2
```

Now I am trying to access data[Job][qs1] in the controller but can't figure it out.

The returned array is;

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [Job] => Array ( [qs1] => 2 ) ) )
```

`$_GET['data[Job][qs1]'];` is not working which is rather odd.

Comment: please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nesting data in your `$_GET` parameters. To access nested array, just try with:

```
$_GET['data']['Job']['qs1']
```

Comment: In CakePHP one should use `CakeRequest` to retrieve the data. `$this->request->query('data.Job.qs1')` or `$this->request->query['data']['Job']['qs1']` ([**Cake 2.x**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters)), or `$this->params['url']['data']['Job']['qs1']` ([**CakePHP 1.3**](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Controllers.html#url)).